# using the min function

Tags: python, python-3.x

If you have got something like

```
d1 = 5, d4 = 4
```

and then call the function

```
min(d1, d4)
```

how can you output `d4` instead of `4`? In other words, I want to output the the variable or index from the minimum function of the smallest value and not the value itself?

Comment: Use argmin with numpy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You rarely want to treat your code (i.e., your variable names) as data. Use a dictionary instead:

```
>>> d = { 'd1': 5, 'd4': 4 }
>>> print min(d, key=d.get)
d4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for` loop:

```
minVal = min(list)
index = 0
for i in xrange(len(list)):
    if (minVal == list[i]):
        index = i
        break
```

Loops through, sees if it is equal, then saves the index and breaks

**EDIT**

You can also use a function I was unaware of under `list.index()`

```
minVal = min(list)
index = list.index(minVal)
```

Comment: This loop can and should be replaced with `list.index(minVal)`.

Comment: @delnan Oh cool hadn't heard of that method before, check edits

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice list comprehension:

```
d = [2, 5, -2, 7, 6, 4]
>>> [index for index, val in enumerate(d) if val == min(d)][0]
2
```

Comment: If you only want a single value from your list comprehension, why not just do `d.index(min(d))`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `index` method of `list` object:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 4, -5, 4, 5, 6]
>>> mylist.index(min(mylist))
6
```

Comment: I don't see how that transcript can be real.  `mylist` only has 2 elements, and so `mylist.index` can't return 2.